# How to check type of value returned from method in a class definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

Given the following example **Button.js**, where a [javascript class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is created:

```
import htmlToElement from './htmlToElement';

class Button {
  constructor() {
    this._html = htmlToElement('<button>simple html</button>');
  }

  render() {
   return this._html;
  }
}
```

The in **./button.spec.js**

```
describe('Rectangle...', function() {
  it(`should be a class constructor..`, function() {
    // how to test against a specific type?
    expect(new Button().render()).to.be('HTMLButtonElement');
  });
});
// note: mocha and chai are included, jsdom is used also. So the button is rendering.
```

How to test this if the returned value of the render function is a HTMLButtonElement?

Comment: `render` returns a *string*, not an HTMLButtonElement

Comment: Well, parse the value into HTML. Although I'd say a way better approach is for `.render` to just return an HTML element

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right, in my development code I have a function which parses the string to html (`.htmlToElement()`). So given that there is a html element, how would you do it then?

Comment: To put it more general, how to test if a returned value is of a certain type?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `expect(new Button().render()).to.be.a('HTMLButtonElement')` will work.